# Choosing the best machine Learning Algorithm for my project

Tags: algorithm

I have 2 columns in my Data Set i.e Magnitude & Location, It need to predict magnitude based on Location input given by user.Suggest me the suitable classifier Algorithm.

Comment: Explore all kinds of regression algorithms. Your data will decide which is the best.

Comment: Being a new contributor on SO, I would suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: shridhar-r-kulkarni what u taking  about??